# Writing data in a grid to a text file with formatiing

Tags: c#, .net, text, datagridview, outputstream

I have a DataGridView in a UI (win form) and now wants to write data in the grid to a text file.

I've tried it with following code. But its not giving the output what I want.

```
public void WriteToTextFile (DataGridView dgv)
        {
            string file_name = "D:\\test1.txt";

        System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;

        objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name);

        int count = dgv.Rows.Count;
        for (int row = 0; row < count-1; row++)
        {
            int colCount = dgv.Rows[row].Cells.Count; 

            for ( int col = 0; col < colCount-1; col++)  
            {
                objWriter.WriteLine(dgv.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString());
            }
        // record seperator could be written here.
        }
        objWriter.Close();
        }
```

Output (only a single item (one grid row) is shown)

```
8130201489

D.I.S.Peter

292331pslr

0100507563

Sharpe Eyes Pvt Ltd

A002    

SalaryFeb11  

110228
```

But the required out put is... (not this should be a single line )

```
8130201489D.I.S.PETER     2923319SLR0100507563SHARPEYES PVT LTD A002          SALARYFEB11    110228      @
```

*How to modify the above code to get this out put?*
Also if I need some additional spaces between words how to insert it? After writing I want to change the extension `.txt` to `.dat` How to do that.

Comment: use Write(text), not WriteLine(text) :). To add a new line, use WriteLine()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not write every value with `WriteLine()`.  Instead, construct each line using a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx), and then write the complete line as output:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;   

public void WriteToTextFile (DataGridView dgv)
{
    String file_name = "D:\\test1.txt";
    using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(file_name))
    {
        for (Int32 row = 0; row < dgv.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (Int32 col = 0; col < dgv.Rows[row].Cells.Count - 1; col++)  
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString()))
                    sb.Append(",");  //any delimiter you choose
                sb.Append(dgv.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString().ToUpper());
            }
            objWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }

    //Rename the file
    File.Move(file_name, Path.ChangeExtension(file_name, "dat"));  //with or without a leading period
}
```

Comment: Hi, actually I need the text in file UPPERCASE. Is it doable in the same method?